# problems converting date to long

Tags: java, date

I am pulling data out of an Excel sheet, to load into Hubspot, using Java.
Here is how the data looks:

this date **2018-12-31** becomes **Dec 31, 2017** once it's in side Hubspot.
This is wrong!

Here is my code:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
                Date dt = null;
                try {
                    dt = df.parse(member.getUsageEndDate());
                } catch (java.text.ParseException e3) {
                    //dt = null;
                    e3.printStackTrace();
                }                                      
                Long l = dt.getTime();
```

If I open the data in Notepad, it looks like this: **31-May-2018**

How can I get this converted properly?

Comment: In GMT it is actually Monday, December 31, 2018 12:00:00 AM

Comment: that worked!  GMT is working. I'll let you know if any problems.

Comment: Mon Dec 31 03:00:00 AST 2018 ???

Answer (score 2):

## tl;dr

```
OffsetDateTime.of( 
    LocalDate.parse( "2018-12-31" ) , 
    LocalTime.MIN , 
    ZoneOffset.UTC 
)
.toInstant()
.toEpochMilli()
```

> 1546214400000

## Details

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using troublesome old date-time classes long ago made legacy by the arrival of the java.time classes built into Java 8 and later.

### ISO 8601

Your input string happens to comply with the [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) standard formats. These formats are used by default in java.time when parsing/generating strings. So no need to specify a formatting pattern.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "2018-12-31" ) ;
```

### First moment of the day

Apparently you need the first moment of the day in UTC for that date. Use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) with constant [`ZoneOffset.UTC`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/ZoneOffset.html#UTC).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.of( ld , LocalTime.MIN , ZoneOffset.UTC ) ;
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "odt.toString(): " + odt );
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/BtZ437).

> odt.toString(): 2018-12-31T00:00Z

### Count-from-epoch

You appear to want the count of milliseconds since the epoch reference date of first moment of 1970 in UTC, 1970-01-01T00:00Z. Extract an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) object, the basic building-block class in java.time, and call its handy [`Instant::toEpochMilli`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) method.

```
long millisecondsSinceEpoch = odt.toInstant().toEpochMilli() ;
```

See this [code run live at IdeOne.com](https://www.ideone.com/BtZ437).

> 1546214400000

Going the other direction.

```
Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochMilli( 1_546_214_400_000L ) ;
```

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).